# telnet localhost 25 auto-disconnect

Tags: postfix-mta, sasl, dovecot

I trying to use telnet on port 25 at localhost but I get disconnected right after connected.

```
"Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host."
```

I can't do nothing...

Here is my main.cf for postfix:

http://pastebin.com/L9PrSNYy

Here the m`aster.cf`

http://pastebin.com/W3muVeGU

Any help ? :/

Answer (score 0):

It should work. Check the logfile for postfix (usually, /var/log/mail.log).
One you can get "EHLO" to work (and see "`STARTTLS`" in the server greeting) you can use this to test TLS connections:

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect 1.2.3.4:25
```

Comment: openssl command return me :
http://pastebin.com/MhsyLGus 
and logs :
http://pastebin.com/3XsQRRAe

Comment: Again, check the postfix logfile.

Comment: Fix your SASL configuration, the HOWTO is at http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

Comment: I updated my main.cf on postfix:
http://pastebin.com/BZ5QrMHE
and sasl/smtpd.cf :
http://pastebin.com/FvrUr5Rd
but still not working